# Can a ClickOnce deployed application read files from disk?

Tags: .net, clickonce, sandbox, file-access

Can an application delivered via ClickOnce in .Net, read Excel and Access files from the users disk?

I know the app is susposed to run in a sandbox, I am curious how partitioned this sandbox is from the rest of the system?

Could the file be read from a network share as well as the users hard drive?

There is an assumption that the user has read access to the files in question.

Thank you,
Keith

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can, but you need to give it the correct permissions.

In the Security tab of the properties pages, check the "Enable ClickOnce Security Settings" and make it a full-trust application, or make it a partial trust app, but specifically give it the FileIO permission.

Comment: Does that raise the requirements on the user's desktop to require more that user privileges?

Comment: I think it simply asks the user for permission to install the application (do you trust the application vendor).